# Custom notification for all user on the record page

Tags: notification, toast, lightning-record-page

I need to create a notification for the object record page. The idea is that there are two or more users on the record page. When one of them changes record status, toats message must be shown for other users (on this record page).

My idea was to create a trigger that fires on record update/insert event, but how can I grab all current users and then display a message for every one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One* way to handle this would be to use the streaming API.

Your record page could have a component that uses the streaming api to listen to changes made on that record and display a toast message in response.

You'll want to familiarize yourself with the empApi docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/code_sample_lightning_cmp.htm

And this code example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation

Additionally,

And just to round out the options:

1. You could do this with platform events in a similar manner. A component listening for the PE.
2. Change Data Capture would be a good bet if you wanted to monitor a limited number of fields

Comment: Thank you. I also have one question. Can I send an event for this empApi from apex?

Comment: @senoron - that's not exactly how the streaming api works. You define a query that's run whenever the record is modified. the results are then broadcast to all empApi clients that are listening.